# entity framework Invalid column name Id (two foreign keys from the same primary table)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I get this error : **Invalid column name 'Resource_Id'** .

I tried the solutions I found on this forum but it doesn't fix my error.

Here is my classes:

```
public class Task 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ApproverResourceId { get; set; }
    public int WorkingResourceId { get; set; }

    public virtual Resource ApproverResource { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource WorkingResource { get; set; }
}
```

Resource Class

```
public class Resource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

ExternalResource

```
public class ExternalResource : Resource
{
    //public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And I added this mapping in my CodeFirst Class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.WorkingResource)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.WorkingResourceId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.ApproverResource)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.ApproverResourceId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the schema of your database? Is it created by entity framework?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't add an image (I need 10 reputations and i just have 6 because I'm new here). I will try to describe my database. I have 3 tables: 1-Tasks (id, Name, ApproverResource, WorkingResource); 2-Resources (Id, creationDate, UpdateDate); ExternalResources(Id,FirstName, LastName). I have 3 relations: Id (Resources) -->ApproverResource(Tasks) ; Id(Resources)-->WorkingResource(Tasks) AND one inheritance Id(Resources) --> Id (ExternalResources).

Comment: You have enough reputation now. Also, try to remove inheritence between Resources and ExternalResources. Also add mapping between Resources and ExternalResources.

Comment: Ok but can you explain me why it s better to remove the inheritance? I did that because i will also have a class for internal resources!

Comment: For EF inheritence means special relation between tables. More [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Comment: I removed ExternalResources class. Now i just have two tables **Tasks** and **Resources** but I still have the same problem  **Invalid column name 'Resource_Id**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 navigation properties because you have 2 foreign keys :

```
public class Resource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> ApproverTasks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> WorkingTasks { get; set; }
}
```

In DbContext you specify them in WithMany:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.WorkingResource)
        .WithMany(r => r.WorkingTasks)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.WorkingResourceId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.ApproverResource)
        .WithMany(r => r.ApproverTasks)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.ApproverResourceId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ExternalResource>()
        .ToTable("ExternalResources");
}
```

You need to explicit tell table name for ExternalResources because of [Table-Per-Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.5) inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it was working for you but in my case , i had to specify the annotation Key + Column order ; in your case on both properties "ResourceId".

I have exactly the same tables configuration without the third one "External".

```
Public class User : EntityBase
{
    [MinLength(5), MaxLength(20), Required]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    [MinLength(3), MaxLength(50),Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FriendRequest> SenderFriendRequests { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FriendRequest> ReceiverFriendRequests { get; set; }
}

public class FriendRequest 
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int SenderId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }
    public virtual User Receiver { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public FriendRequestStatus RequestStatus { get; set; }
}
```

If i don't specify those annotations EF throws me a DataException with the message :

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>       Server.DAL.Context.FriendRequest: : EntityType 'FriendRequest' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>       FriendRequests: EntityType: EntitySet 'FriendRequests' is based on type 'FriendRequest' that has no keys defined.